# style binding issue when the () are not included

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can someone please clarify the following situation with Knockout.JS style bindings?

If I use functions like Width(), Height() the bindings are successful, but when I use the properties without the () the bindings are not successful. For the attr binding I don`t have to use ().

Successful attr and style bindigs:

```
<div class="container" id="container" data-bind="foreach: Nodes">
    <div class="node" data-bind="attr:{id:Id}, style: {width: Width() + 'px', height: Height() + 'px', left: PositionLeft() + 'px', top: PositionTop() + 'px'}">
        <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>    <div class="ep"></div>
    </div>
```

attr bindings applied but style bindings are not successful

```
<div class="container" id="container" data-bind="foreach: Nodes">
    <div class="node" data-bind="attr:{id:Id}, style: {width: Width + 'px', height: Height + 'px', left: PositionLeft + 'px', top: PositionTop + 'px'}">
        <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>    <div class="ep"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with observables, then you would need to call them as a function to retrieve their value, if you are using them in an expression (like `Width() + 'px'`).

If you are simply passing an observable (not some type of expression), then the bindings are smart enough to unwrap that observable.

So, `text: myObservable` is fine, but `text: myObservable() + '!'` would require the parens.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using expressions in your style binding, you're appending `px` to the width.

[The data-bind syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)

```
<!-- variable (usually a property of the current view model -->
<div data-bind="visible: shouldShowMessage">...</div>

<!-- comparison and conditional -->
The item is <span data-bind="text: price() > 50 ? 'expensive' : 'cheap'"></span>.

<!-- function call and comparison -->
<button data-bind="enable: parseAreaCode(cellphoneNumber()) != '555'">...</button>

<!-- function expression -->
<div data-bind="click: function (data) { myFunction('param1', data) }">...</div>

<!-- object literal (with unquoted and quoted property names) -->
<div data-bind="with: {emotion: 'happy', 'facial-expression': 'smile'}">...</div>
```